# Converting from datenum back to actual time

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, date-conversion

Ok, so I've been messing with what should be a simple problem.  I'm trying to plot an numerical array (double) vs. the associated time stamp (cell) with the format of the DD-MM-YY HH:MM:SS (for example: 13-Mar-15 07:23:10). 
I'm able to plot a single set using `datetime(time stamp)`.  Due to the data set it outputs the nice HH:MM on the x-axis.  Very nice.

Now in order to plot 2 sets of values on the same graph, I've found that Matlab doesn't like to use the date_time twice for the x-axis, so then I go to the infamous `datenum` function, which is able to plot both on the same graph.  However, it's in the serial value of time and it jacks with my plot sizing (i.e. the x-axis doesn't autosize).

With what should be a simple problem has actually caused me days scouring the internet trying to reconvert it back to my beloved HH:MM after converting the "time stamp" into the serial time.

I don't think that a code sample or data set should be necessary for example purposes. (but can provide if needed)

I've tried to use the `datetick` function, but can't get seem to get it working.

Comment: Two solutions, but I might be misunderstanding your problem. 1) Why not align the time series data so that they align to the same timestamp on the axes? 2) Why not plot a graph with 2 axes, 1 for each set?

Answer (score 0):

The trick with `datenum` and `datetick` is to set limits and tick positions before you call datetick, then make sure it doesn't redo them.

So, after plotting your two sets of data against the datenums it would go something like:

```
step = 1/24; % for hourly - adjust to preference
ticks = datenum('mystarttime'):step:datenum('myendtime')
set(gca,'XTick',ticks)
datetick('x','HH:MM','keepticks','keeplimits')
```

Comment: You people saved me, and my company whatever it is that they are ultimately paying me an hour!   It works beautifully.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I work a lot with time series and most often I have to plot my data versus time/date.

Since Matlab never gave me a definitively convenient solution, for many years now I work this way:

I defined once and for all a Matlab shortcut (in the matlab shortcut toolbar):
[image: shortcut toolbar]

containing the following code:

```
xticktemp = get(gca,'Xtick') ;
ticklabel = {datestr(xticktemp(1)) datestr(xticktemp(2:end),15) } ;
set(gca,'Xticklabel',ticklabel)
clear xticktemp ticklabel
```

---

I convert all my times with `datenum` and use this format for working (*or posix time when more convenient, but it's another story*), calculating and plotting. When I need to now exactly the time of an event in a human readable format, I press the shortcut and I obtain something like:

[image: timeticks]

Of course there are 2 major limitations with this method:

- This does not control the steps of the ticks (it just replicate what Matlab initially set)
- You have to re-click your shortcut to refresh the tick labels everytime you zoom or pan the figure

For these reasons, when I need to finalize figure for presentation to others I won't use this trick and define my ticks exactly like I want them, but when you are simply working away, this shortcut has saved me hours (may be even days?) of fiddling around over the last 10 years ....